# jQuery: Performing synchronous AJAX request followed by a chain of other ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have an ASP.NET MVC app and I am trying to make a chain of operations, one after another using jQuery inside a javascript function. The function consists of three parts.

What I am trying to do is: If some condition is satisfied then I want to execute syncrhonous jQuery ajax call CheckData. Dependending on the result returned:

- It returns ok -> I want to continue executing part2 and finally part3 in this order.
- It returns Nok -> then it finishes and returns. It does not continue executing part2 and part3.

So I have set async: false but it is not working, program continues executing part2 and part3.
I know async:false is deprecated so how can I achieve this?

```
function onCheckValidData()
{
    // do something....

    // PART 1 STARTS HERE

    if (some_condition_is_satified)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CheckData", "MyController")',
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            beforeSend: function () {
                showLoading();
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (!result.isOk) {
                    return;
                }
            },
            complete: function(){
                hideLoading();
            }
        });
    }

    // PART 2 STARTS HERE

    // do something.....
    // continue doing more thing.....
    // more things.....

    // PART 3 STARTS HERE

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("MyActionMethod1", "MyController")?' + paramsStr,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        beforeSend: function () {
            showLoading();
        },
        success: function (result) {
            if (result == 'True') {
                jsMethod2();  // jsMethod2 is another javascript method which contains another $.ajax block
            }
            else if (result == 'False') {
                jsMethod3(); // jsMethod3 is another javascript method which contains another $.ajax block
            }
            else {
                alert(result);
            }
        },
        complete: function(){
            hideLoading();
        }
    });
}
```

My actions in the controller:

```
    private JsonResult CheckData()
    {
        MyBoolResult res = new MyBoolResult();

        // do something....

        return Json(new { isOk = res.isOk });
    }


    public String MyActionMethod1(String param1, String param2, bool param3, string param4, string param5)
    {

       // do something

       return condition ? "True" : "False";
    }
```

Comment: There is no excuse for using synchronous AJAX. Do not do it. To achieve what you need simply put the other AJAX requests in their own functions and invoke them from the callback of their dependent AJAX call, passing data in arguments if required.

Comment: Taking a step back... Why do you *want* these requests to be synchronous?  What is the actual behavior you're trying to achieve in your application?  Starting from the behavior you should be able to model your asynchronous operations to achieve that behavior.

Comment: why don't you just use ajax in ajax ? `if(result.isOk) { // Run the second part here } else { return false; }`

Comment: @David I need synchronous calls because I need to execute them in that order. I have successfully applied Mischa solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to make that synchornuous. If u want the "PART 2" and "PART 3" to wait for the ajax-request to finish just put them into a function and call them on success:

```js
function onCheckValidData()
{
    // do something....

    // PART 1 STARTS HERE
    if (some_condition_is_satified)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CheckData", "MyController")',            
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            beforeSend: function () {
                showLoading();
            },
            //Success will execute only if the ajax-request is finised
            success: function (result) {
                if (!result.isOk) {
                    return;
                }
                part2(); 
                part3();
            },
            complete: function(){
                hideLoading();
            }
        });
    }

    // PART 2 STARTS HERE
    function part2 () {/*do something.....*/}

    // PART 3 STARTS HERE
    function part3 () {/*$.ajax({...})*/}
}
```

Comment: I have applied your solution and it works correctly. Thx.